UK Probate Record Unavailable
I searched the online here but found no record for a certain person of known name and date of death.
I realise that probate is not always demanded if the deceased's assets are low or if the principal assets are jointly owned.
But that isn't the case here surely.
His main assets were his home in UK and a 99% stake in the firm that managed his music recordings. The remaining 1% share being owned by the deceased's manager - also a sibling.
I note from accounts and returns for the recording/music management company that the deceased's share capital changed at the year of death from 99% to 26% - the remaining 74% being in the name of his manager.
My question is why no will in this case ?

Sounds like there was either a will or a clause in the founding document of the company.


Could such a clause or will be added later if say when the majority shareholder (who became the deceased) were undergoing a dangerous medical procedure ? 2. The company assets apart, shouldn't there be a will for the private property of the deceased, e.g. house, fixtures & fittings, personal effects like musical instruments, book collection, paintings, photos, gold disc awards, etc ? 3. If the house was in fact the property of the music management company, would personal effects be covered by a will or would they simply be distributed to next-of-kin ?


It sounds very plausible that in an estate with two main assets that both passed by non-probate transfers at death. Non-probate transfers are quite common in both residential real estate and closely held company shares. If 26% is held in the name of the decedent, it is also plausible (depending upon the timing of the death) that there will be a probate commenced and it hasn't happened yet. Also, are you confident that the name you know for the decedent is their true name and not a stage name?

also note: Not all wills are archived at courts - some are just executed by family.

@ohwilleke Yes, I am absolutely sure of the legal name of the deceased, as listed on the death record and company returns/accounts. The death  was 20-30 years ago. No UK  probate would take that long unless it was contested to the highest courts - in which case we'd all know about it. I think it is a non-probate transfer for the main 2 items as you suggest. But the remaining personal effects - in this case of considerable collectors value, up to maybe $500,000 - should be probate. No wife or kids. Just a mother and brother/manager. As such you'd think the mother got this stuff . . .

@Trunk if the person was wealthy, most of their assets may have been held in trusts - they don’t count as testimony assets.

Also, are you sure their probate was in England or Wales - if they lived in say, New York or California, it’s possible their will was dealt with there.

The use of trusts, and moreover offshore trusts, in the record business is well-known from the 1970s. When I first started looking at this I thought trusts would come into it. But so far it just seems like bog-standard limited companies in UK law. The deceased was not a UK national and once had some overseas assets. But the major overseas asset, i.e. a holiday cottage, had been sold to some other celebrity years prior to death. I did look in that country's wills archive but found no record of a will under deceased's legal name. Deceased toured and recorded in US but never lived there.
